# screen orientation ionic cutting view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, screen-orientation

I'm having a small problem but i don't know how to solve it...

I'm using ionic with cordova and the plugin net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation for screen orientation...

the problem is that when I go to the page where the orientation should change, the plugin first cuts the view in half, changes it orientation and then put the view to te size it should be.

The problem is that this transition is easy to see and kind off ugly:x

the funciton where I call screen orientation is:

```
function changeOrientation() {
    console.log("changing screen orientation");
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
    $timeout.cancel(timerToChangeOrientation);
}
```

and this function is called when the device is ready inside a timeout of 1 s that i puted to minimize the problem with the transition.